# ld: library not found for -lStripe

Tags: ios, react-native, linker, stripe-payments, xcodebuild

I am attempting to use the tipsi-stripe library: https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

I have followed the manual installation instructions as listed in the README (added `TPSStripe.xcodeproj` to Libraries, etc) and run `react-native link` as well as `react-native link tipsi-stripe` (succesfully I might add)

However when I run `react-native run-ios`, or build with xcode I get:

```
ld: library not found for -lStripe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/myApp normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/flockCover.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the never-ending issue and it is actually not about library code, but about Xcode build approach.

I believe there is no particular way to solve it for all cases because each case may be different.
We have some tickets about react-native + libraries, where you may find a working solution for your case:

- https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/95
- https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/11
- https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/55